# If Statement in PHP Function

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I have a function which outputs a variable in a certain color depending on the contents of said variable, however it is currently outputting the same response to the IF statement even if the IF statement is not true

```
function info($ride) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `qtd` WHERE `name` = '$ride'");
    $rideinfo = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $time = $rideinfo["time"];

    if ($time != "Unavailable" || $time != "CLOSED") {
        echo "<center><font color=\"228B22\"><b>$time</b></font></center>";
    }

    if ($time == "Unavailable" || $time == "CLOSED") {
        echo "<center><font color=\"B22222\">$time</font></center>";
    }
}
```

Currently `$time` is always being outputted with #228B22 even if the value of `$time = "Unavailable"` or `"CLOSED"`

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 5):

You have to change your first condition, because it's always `true`:

```
if ($time != "Unavailable" && $time != "CLOSED"){echo "<center><font color=\"228B22\"><b>$time</b></font></center>";}   
if ($time == "Unavailable" || $time == "CLOSED"){echo "<center><font color=\"B22222\">$time</font></center>";}
```

In that case you can also change it to if-else statement:

```
if ($time != "Unavailable" && $time != "CLOSED"){
    echo "<center><font color=\"228B22\"><b>$time</b></font></center>";
} else {
    echo "<center><font color=\"B22222\">$time</font></center>";
}
```